# Using org in emacs batch mode

Tags: org-mode, start-up, batch-mode

I'd like to export an org file to LaTeX from the command line. I have created a file `export.el` with the following contents (simplified to reproduce the problem):

```
(require 'org)

(when (not (assoc "scrreprt" org-latex-classes))
  (push '("scrreprt"
          (assoc "report" org-latex-classes))
        org-latex-classes))

 (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect "contents.org")
   (org-latex-export-to-latex nil nil nil t)))
```

And then I tried to run it from the shell:

```
$ emacs -Q --batch -l export.el 
Symbol's value as variable is void: org-latex-classes
```

It seems that I am missing some org functionality. How do I find out what else I have to `require` in order to get `org-latex-classes` defined?

(Omitting the `-Q` option does not help either, but even if it helped my question about finding the right `require` would stand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you have access to `org-latex-classes` when you start
up Emacs for interactive use, so something in your `init` file is
loading it.  You can check which library defines
`org-latex-classes` with `C-h v org-latex-classes` (or
`describe-variable`).  It tells you that

> `org-latex-classes` is a variable defined in `ox-latex.el`.

As such, you also need to `(require 'ox-latex)` for Emacs to
recognize that variable.  It should also work to `(require 'ox)`
instead.

Also see [this SuperUser post on the question](https://superuser.com/questions/896741/how-do-i-configure-org-latex-classes-in-emacs).